# Inline thymeleaf property into Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to [inline](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart) a Spring *application.properties* entry into Javascript.

Works fine:

```
<h1 th:utext="${@environment.getProperty('key')}"></h1>
```

Produces null:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    ...

    var user = /*[[${key}]]*/ null;

    ...
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

What is the correct syntax? When I try to use *@environment* inside the script tag I get another error:

```
Error: $compile:tpload
Error Loading Template
```

Answer (score 2):

Just

```
[[${@environment.getProperty('key')}]]
```

works, without the other stuff, written in the Thymeleaf docs.